# GUI doesn't Display anymore when i combine JinternalFrame with Server Socket application

Tags: java, sockets

i have a client/server application working perfectly. Now I just looked at JInternalFrames from the oracle website and thought of combining my Socket Server application with the JinternalFrames, so that a frame is generated to display each incoming message in its Text area from client.There's just one client.
Now my problems are:
1) GUI of InternalFrames doesn't display anymore, but I can see socket thread running.
2) Does anybody know how or has any article which might give me an insight on how to dynamically create new frames to display each incoming message from Client? Its a one client/ one server application.

here is my code

```
public class InternalFrameDemo extends JFrame
                               implements ActionListener {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
        private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    JDesktopPane desktop;

    public InternalFrameDemo() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane
        createFrame(); //create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Set up the lone menu.
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Document");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        //Set up the first menu item.
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("new");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        //Set up the second menu item.
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_Q, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.setActionCommand("quit");
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        return menuBar;
    }

    //React to menu selections.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("new".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { //new
            createFrame();
        } else { //quit
            quit();
        }
    }

    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {

        MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
       // JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Print");
 JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
 area.setText("This is a simple area text ");
 area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
 frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);

       JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
                buttonPane.add(b1);
        b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        b1.setActionCommand("quit");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
       frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}

        //socket connection
         StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0007); // Server socket
                        System.out.println("server started listening on port:0007");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 5000");
        }
                while (true) {
            try {


                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                //message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                               // while(message != null)
                                 while( (message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                 everything.append(message+"\n");
                                }
                                 area.setText(everything.toString());
                                 inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }


    }

    }

    //Quit the application.
    protected void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
         //Create and set up the window.
        InternalFrameDemo frame = new InternalFrameDemo();

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Document #" + (++openFrameCount), 
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

        //...Then set the window size or call pack...
        setSize(300,300);

        //Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
    }
}
```

I will greatly appreciate any help...Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer...U Sir are truly a MadProgrammer.Now I've got the application running and Displaying the GUI.My only problem is dynamically creating a new internal frame to display each message from the client.Do u please have any articles or advise to help me accomplish this last hurdle??...Thank you again

Comment: [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are blocking on the `accept` call. This is easy to check - use `jps` to find the process id (pid) and then `jstack` (or similar). You need to be running blocking networking code on different threads.

(Standard advice about your code: Don't use static [mutable] variables. Don't extend classes you don't need to. Use a separate listener class for each action. Use try-with-resource to ensure you release resources.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't vote up Tom's answer (not enough points etc)but he's correct. Your accept method is blocking that thread and you are launching your UI in the same thread. Would have to agree, change your code so that the UI thread is as de-coupled from the network thread as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I've understood what u've suggested. But how can I do it. How do I de-couple the UI thread from the network thread? Please Isn't there an example I can look at.

Comment: Have a look at MVC design patterns, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm Your UI should just be your UI, It does not need to know anything about your client or have any client side (I'm referring to client server code here) code, all it needs to do is expose some method to allow you to display whatever it is on screen.